# Suppress the display of the input into the TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a winforms program containing a `RichTextBox`.
The user inputs the text into the RichTextBox.
I wish to receive the input through keyboard events and not through textBox1.Text property, validate the string and only display it in the RichTextBox later.
How can I prevent the RichTextBox from displaying the input text by the user, even though the user inputs the text into the RichTextBox?
The RichTextBox is selected and has focus.
I am sorry. I just wanted to simplify the issue and therefore I neglected to mention that **it is not a TextBox but a RichTextBox**. It turns out that it matters, as the proposed solution is based on the PassowrdChar property, which is not natively supported by RichTextBox. I do not wish to create an inherited class for a property which is not even being used as such, only to suppress displaying the user input at input time.

Comment: Why would you not want to display the string? Is it like a password string ******** ?

Comment: Set the TextBox's [PasswordChar Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar(v=vs.110).aspx) can hide the text.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the KeyDown event. By doing that, you have an ability to validate the user input.

[Tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/textbox)

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //
    // Detect the KeyEventArg's key enumerated constant.
    //
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("You pressed enter! Good job!");
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("You pressed escape! What's wrong?");
    }
}
```

With that said, you have to store user input in string variable, validate it through the event and only then set variable value in textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    char c = e.KeyChar;
    // ..
    // handle the character as needed
    // ..

    e.Handled = true;  // suppress the RTB from receiving it
}
```

Note that you may or may not want to treat mouse events like right mouseclicks to control inserting via the mouse..